# How to change a value of a variable in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I create a `Variable` in TensorFlow:

```
c = tf.Variable([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], tf.float32)
```

Then I define a placeholder:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
```

After that I define a function (computational graph) combining the two above defined objects:

```
y = x + c
```

After that I "initialize" the global variables:

```
s = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
s.run(init)
```

Finally, I can run my function:

```
s.run(y, {x : [10.0, 20.0, 30.0]})
```

Now, I want to change the value of `c`. Is it possible in TensorFlow? I tried for example:

```
c = tf.assign(c, [1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
```

and also:

```
c = tf.Variable([1.0, 1.0, 1.0], tf.float32)
```

Nothing works. Whenever I call

```
s.run(y, {x : [10.0, 20.0, 30.0]})
```

I still get the old result (corresponding to the old / initial value of `c`).

So, how do I assign a new value to a global variables in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After assigning a new value to the variable `c` with one of the methods you used, you need to evaluate it:

```
c.eval(session=s)
```

or

```
s.run(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

After assigning new values to variable 'c', you got to make session initialize new values,

```
c = tf.assign(c, [1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
s.run(c)
s.run(y, {x : [10.0, 20.0, 30.0]})
array([ 11.,  21.,  31.], dtype=float32)
```